# How to get SlidingMenu above TabHost?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am using the [Sliding Menu Library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) with MonoDroid and MvvmCross. However when I call menu.ShowMenu(); the tabs are still visible.

How do I either; 
a) Make the Tables slide across with the rest of the screen? 
b) Set the tabs to invisible from the MvxBindingActivityView?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you supply any any images of what you are experiencing, or any sample code for what your current setup is.

Comment: I think I've got a working solution. Instead of using the Sliding Menu Library I have just created a FrameLayout for each layout that needs this sliding menu.